# How can I import a module from a pyc file or so file in Pypy?

Tags: python, module, cpython, pypy

This i my scenario:
I have a python project that runs in cPython.
and I have some .pyc, .so files in this project, and I don't have these files's source code.
This project runs well in cPython.
But if I change the interpreter to pypy, it can't import these modules which contained by the .pyc files and .so files.
Is there any way that I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to decompile the code to get back some semblance of *.py files. There are various projects out there to do this: search for "python decompile". Sponsoring one of the efforts would probably go a long way towards getting a working decompiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got uncompyle6 to decompile these .pyc files already. But how can I import those module which are compiled in .so files?

Comment: > But how can I import those module which are compiled in .so files?

I don't think you can

Comment: ok, I get it. It's really a pity that I have to find the source code first so that I could go on.
thanks again, my dear friend!